# Proof that the distibution sequence $\int_{0}^{\infty}(tanh(nx)-1)\phi(x)dx \to 0$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, distribution-theory

Let $T:\phi \mapsto \langle T_f,\phi\rangle =\int _{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\phi(x)dx$, 
where $\phi(x)$ is a test function, be a distribution. I would like to prove that the sequence of distributions:
\begin{equation}
\langle T_{f{_n}},\phi\rangle=\int _{-\infty}^{\infty}(tanh(nx)-1)\phi(x)dx \to 
\langle T_{f{}},\phi\rangle=-\int _{-\infty}^{0}\phi(x)dx+ \int _{0}^{\infty}\phi(x)dx
\end{equation}
with:
\begin{equation}
f_n(x)=tanh(nx)
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \to \pm \infty}f_n(x)=f(x)=\begin{cases}
-1, & x<0 \\
1, & x>0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

I know that I have to prove that the integral:
\begin{equation}
|\langle T_{f{n}},\phi\rangle-\langle T_{f{}},\phi\rangle|=\int_{0}^{\infty}(tanh(nx)-1)\phi(x)dx \to 0
\end{equation}
In this case I must show somehow that:

1. The sequence: $\{g_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}=\{(tanh(nx)-1)\phi(x)\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly to a function $f$, $\forall \phi \in D{\mathbb{(R)}}$.
2. The functions $\{g_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ are Riemann integrable.

Are the above right? If yes, how am I supposed to prove the uniform convergence? I do know that they are Riemann integrable since they are continuous and supp$g_n=[a,b]$ a compact interval. Can you please guide me throught the procedure since it is the first kind of exercise that I am trying to do on distributions and I would like to have an example to start with. Thank you all!

Comment: As $\phi$ has a compact support, you can easily use Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem to prove your claim ;)

Comment: Could it be easy for you to guide me through the process? I am new to the whole concept of distributions :/

Comment: Update: I corrected the distribution to which I would like my sequence to converge to.

Answer (score 1):

You have that $f_n \phi \to f \phi$ pointwise

As $|f_n (x) \phi(x)| \leq |\phi(x)|$, $f_n \phi$ is dominated by $|\phi|$, that is an integrable fontion.

Hence, all the hypothesis of the [Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) are satisfied, and this imply that

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f_n (x) \phi(x)-f(x)\phi(x)| dx = 0$$